Deserialize json object as a string
I have a class A that has a field string data.
I perform a server request that gets me a json text that I convert to A:
var a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>(jsonResponse);

The problem is sometimes data comes as a string (e.g: Ball) and sometimes it comes as a json object, like this:
"data" : {
    "field1" : "Ball",
    "field2" : "Foo"
}

And this breaks the deserialization, since the field data was expecting a string.
Is there a way to capture data from the json text as a string even if it comes as a json object?

Why not make the property an object, then deal with the type as needed?

My habit when dealing with variable JSON is to parse rather than deserialize and then look at the properties to see which kind it is

Looks like you are using Newtonsoft? How about making data a JObject?

Followed @gunr2171 suggestion and it worked!

If you want data to support both JSON strings and JSON objects, you should make data be a JToken not a JObject.  See JSON.NET: Why Use JToken--ever?.

How about something like this as a starting point? (inspired by .NET TryParse methods):
public static bool TryDeserialize<T>(string jsonString, out T result)
{
    try
    {
        result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonString)!;
        return result is not null;
    }
    catch
    {
        result = default!;
        return false;
    }
}

Then you can use it like:
if (TryDeserialize<YourObjectModel>(jsonString, out YourObjectModel result))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"result is {result.Field1}");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(jsonString)} value is {jsonString}");
}


No idea how this would help. It's just doing the same thing I already do but returning a true or false to tell if it succeeded.

@Daniel It helps you to decide if the JSON string is in the format of a particular type or not. If it is, you're good to go, if it is not, you know that it contains the simple string, e.g. "Ball".  So, the mismatch type won't "...And this breaks the deserialization"...

Got it. My intention wasn't trying to see if the deserialization would fail, this information I already had. I wanted it to succeed in the specific case where a string (in my class) received a json object from the server. Changing the string to an object did the job, but I got your idea.

You can deserialize your json into dynamic object instead of concrete class
dynamic objX = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(Test2);

How about declaring two separate DTO classes, when it is string deserialize to B, if it is json object deserialize to A
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Dynamic;

public class A
{
    public Data data{get;set;}
}

public class B
{
    public string data{get;set;}
}

public class Data
{
    public string field1{get;set;}
    public string field2{get;set;}
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string Test1 = "{\"data\":\"strTest\"}";
        string Test2 = "{\"data\":{\"field1\":\"strTest1\", \"field2\":\"strTest2\"}}";
        //var obj1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>(Test1);//fails
        //obj1.Dump();
        //var obj2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>(Test2);
        //obj2.Dump();
        dynamic objX = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(Test2);//try switching Test1
        if(objX.data.GetType()==typeof(string))
        {
            //its a string  
            var obj1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<B>(Test1);//fails
            obj1.Dump();
        }
        else
        {
            //its a json object
            var obj2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>(Test2);
            obj2.Dump();
        }
    }
}

fiddle here https://dotnetfiddle.net/EJkdMW

I don't think this works for my case. These strings Test1 and Test2 are different from the json that comes from my server. The class A has a lot of fields and so has the json, data is just one of the json fields, I couldn't try to deserialize only data because the deserialization breaks before I have its information. Nice idea though.

maybe you can update the question adding the  json that comes from the server

It's literally the second paragraph. "I perform a server request that gets me a json text that I convert to A"

It's still not clear what are the two responses from server

It's very clear. It is either a string (e.g: Ball) or a json object, which you can visualize as a Dictionary<string, string>. There is an example in the question.
